# Tab-view in Chrome and IE

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following jsfiddle set up for a tab-view, and it works. 
For some reason though, it wont switch the panes in Chrome and IE.

And i really need to know why.

http://jsfiddle.net/RYYGu/

Comment: it works fine for me (I tried in IE9 and Chrome)

Comment: I know this isn't what you asked, but you've only got -moz-border-radius set. Might want to add a border-radius style as well. Works for me in chrome as well.

Comment: Did you include both of  the libraries? <script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: works fine for me as well on all browsers

Answer (score 0):

Looks to be working just fine for me.

Comment: Which libraries did you include?

Comment: I didn't do anything but click on your jsfiddle link.

Answer (score 0):

The tabs are working fine in Chrome and IE for me.

If you're referring to the hyperlinks not working, you are linking to the **current** tab on each tab. Try linking to `#second` from the first tab, for example.

If you're wanting the URL hash to change when you change tabs, you can hook into the [`show`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#event-show) event, then change the window.location.hash to the tab id.